# How can I find rows related to a specific table in fn_dblog()

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

From the various info I have read about `fn_dblog()` in MS-SQL, I thought that `AllocUnitName` contained the table name. But recently, I was checking for deletion of a specific table's row but could not find its name in the results returned by `fn_dblog(null,null)`. There are rows that have `dbo.MyTable.PK_xxxx` but nothing with just `dbo.MyTable`. This is a table that has tens of transactions daily so I am wondering if `AllocUnitName` is the correct place to look for the table name. I am using MS-SQL 2008 R2 here.

So, if `AllocUnitName` is not the right place to look, where should I look in the results returned by fn_dblog(null,null) to get records specific to a specific table.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, who knows? `fn_dblog()` is not documented or supported, so it's impossible to say what the information it returns really means.

Having said that, I guess that `db.MyTable.PK_xxxx` is the primary key of the table, and since by default PKs are clustered and the clustered index contains the table data, it *is* the table in a certain sense. Therefore I would assume that `AllocUnitName` is indeed what you want, but using undocumented system procedures is always at your own risk and you should not expect any guaranteed answers.

Comment: Yes, they are not documented but they are not a secret either. The SQL dev team themselves blog about it. Paul Randal explained here why they are not documented: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Why-are-so-many-DBCC-commands-undocumented.aspx

I will check if AllocUnitName used the primary key as you have suggested.